# Tmux: Unable to switch panes when in copy mode?

Tags: tmux

I have tried copying and pasting my coworker's tmux.conf config to mine and running `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`. It seems to have updated (I can tell because the colors have been updated)

He has a config where he can switch panes with `option + hjkl`. I can also do this.

However, when I'm in copy mode (`option + u`) and scrolling up and down, I am unable to switch panes with `option + hjkl`, but he can.

Is there something I'm missing? Here's the config:

```
set -g prefix C-e
unbind C-b
bind C-e send-prefix

# Window mappings
bind -n M-h select-pane -L
bind -n M-j select-pane -D
bind -n M-k select-pane -U
bind -n M-l select-pane -R

# Enable OSX clipboard copying
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy'

bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

set-option -g renumber-windows on

# Navigate between windows
bind -n M-n next-window
bind -n M-p previous-window
bind -n M-c new-window -c '#{pane_current_path}'

# open split
bind -n M-\ split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'
bind -n M-- split-window -v -c '#{pane_current_path}'

# open split with vim
unbind ^W
bind ^W split-window -p 25 -c '#{pane_current_path}' '/usr/bin/env vim .' \; swap-pane -D
#
# start new tab of pane in current directory
bind '"' split-window -c '#{pane_current_path}'
bind % split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'
bind c new-window -c '#{pane_current_path}'

# resizing
bind-key -nr    M-Up resize-pane -U
bind-key -nr  M-Down resize-pane -D
bind-key -nr  M-Left resize-pane -L
bind-key -nr M-Right resize-pane -R

bind-key -n M-u copy-mode

unbind ^E
bind ^E select-pane -t :.+

set -s escape-time 0
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

######################
### DESIGN CHANGES ###
######################

# panes
set -g pane-border-fg black
set -g pane-active-border-fg brightred

## Status bar design
# status line
set -g status-justify left
set -g status-bg default
set -g status-fg colour12
set -g status-interval 2

# messaging
set -g message-fg black
set -g message-bg yellow
set -g message-command-fg blue
set -g message-command-bg black

#window mode
setw -g mode-bg colour6
setw -g mode-fg colour0

# window status
setw -g window-status-format " #F#I:#W#F "
setw -g window-status-current-format " #F#I:#W#F "
setw -g window-status-format "#[fg=magenta]#[bg=black] #I #[bg=cyan]#[fg=colour8] #W "
setw -g window-status-current-format "#[bg=brightmagenta]#[fg=colour8] #I #[fg=colour8]#[bg=colour14] #W "
setw -g window-status-current-bg colour0
setw -g window-status-current-fg colour11
setw -g window-status-current-attr dim
setw -g window-status-bg green
setw -g window-status-fg black
setw -g window-status-attr reverse

# Info on left (I don't have a session display for now)
set -g status-left ''

# loud or quiet?
set-option -g visual-activity off
set-option -g visual-bell off
set-option -g visual-silence off
set-window-option -g monitor-activity off
set-option -g bell-action none

set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

# The modes {
setw -g clock-mode-colour colour135
setw -g mode-attr bold
setw -g mode-fg colour196
setw -g mode-bg colour238

# }
# The panes {

set -g pane-border-bg colour235
set -g pane-border-fg colour238
set -g pane-active-border-bg colour236
set -g pane-active-border-fg colour51

# }
# The statusbar {

set -g status-position bottom
set -g status-bg colour234
set -g status-fg colour137
set -g status-attr dim
set -g status-left ''
set -g status-right '#[fg=colour233,bg=colour241,bold] %d/%m #[fg=colour233,bg=colour245,bold] %H:%M:%S '
set -g status-right-length 50
set -g status-left-length 20

setw -g window-status-current-fg colour81
setw -g window-status-current-bg colour238
setw -g window-status-current-attr bold
setw -g window-status-current-format ' #I#[fg=colour250]:#[fg=colour255]#W#[fg=colour50]#F '

setw -g window-status-fg colour138
setw -g window-status-bg colour235
setw -g window-status-attr none
setw -g window-status-format ' #I#[fg=colour237]:#[fg=colour250]#W#[fg=colour244]#F '

setw -g window-status-bell-attr bold
setw -g window-status-bell-fg colour255
setw -g window-status-bell-bg colour1

# }
# The messages {

set -g message-attr bold
set -g message-fg colour232
set -g message-bg colour166

# }
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, added this:

```
# Switch panes while in copy mode
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi M-h select-pane -L
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi M-j select-pane -D
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi M-k select-pane -U
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi M-l select-pane -R
```